# Why this simple arithmetic function does not type check?

Tags: haskell

Why this definition fails in GHCi?

```
let f = (*2)+1
```

With

```
No instance for (Num (a0 -> a0))
  arising from a use of `+'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a0 -> a0))
In the expression: (* 2) + 1
In an equation for `f': f = (* 2) + 1
```

How is it different from the following?

```
let f x = x*2+1
```

Comment: `(*2)` is a function. `x*2` is a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(*2)` is a function. So you're trying to add `1` to a function, which does not work (barring a `Num` instance for functions).

Comment: worth pointing out that were you to define a num instance for functions it would do the right thin

Comment: @PhilipJF: Even if there were a Num instance for functions, I think it would still be a type error because `(+)` expects both its arguments to be the same type.

Comment: @missingo they would be though, right?  `(*2) :: Num a => a -> a` while `1 :: Num a => a -> a` after specialization to functions (`fromInteger`, baby)

Answer (score 8):

`(*2)` defines a function of type `Num a => a -> a`, the same as

```
let multTwo x = x * 2
```

so you are trying to add 1 to a function.

You can use composition instead:

```
let f = (+1) . (*2)
```

Comment: Actually, your `multTwo` is `(2*)`,  not `(*2)`. For multiplication, which is commutative, it is of course not much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

As per the other answers, you're trying to add 1 to a function.

I can see what you're trying to do, though; something like 'in front' currying:

```
let f = \x -> x * 2 + 1
```

which is the same as

```
let f x = x * 2 + 1
```

As per Lee's answer, `f = (+ 1) . (* 2)` applies everything as you'd expect.  You can also do something like this to apply everything the other way around:

```
import Control.Arrow

let f = (* 2) >>> (+ 1)           

-- Prelude Control.Arrow> f 5
-- 11
```

Which might be more along the lines of what you're thinking in your head.